# Why is a stray semicolon no longer detected by `-pedantic` modern compilers?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, gcc-pedantic

The following snippet generates compilation errors on adding [`-pedantic`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-pedantic-1) and [`-Werror`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Werror) on compilers that are a bit old.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int add(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}; // <-- stray semicolon

int main (){
    return 0;
}
```

However this does not happen newer compiler versions. Please find a matrix of GCC ([10.x](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) and [11.x](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-11/)) and Clang (5.x, 6.x) demonstrating the difference at https://godbolt.org/z/KWeb8WTxz.

I have two parts to my question:

1. Why is this not triggered in recent compilers?
2. Is it possible to enable the old behaviour in recent versions of Clang or GCC?

Comment: Because it's legal in all declaration contexts now. It wasn't before C++14 (in class scope) even though compiles allowed it.

Comment: `-Wextra-semi` catches those.

Comment: Reminds me of https://xkcd.com/1172/

Comment: Note that `-Wextra-semi` is documented in [C++ Dialect Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html) and not in the more general [Options to Request or Suppress Warning Messages](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html).  It is marked "C++, Objective C++ only".

Comment: It’s best to remove superfluous semis as they litter the code. Yard inquiries pointed out ⟶ that they
ad bîn “provòked” ay A fork, of à grave Brofèsor; àth é’s Brèak— fast — table;  ; acùtely profèššionally piquéd, to=introdùce a notion of time [ùpon à plane (?) sù ’ ’ fàç’e’] by pùnct! ingh oles (sic) in iSpace?!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Starting in C++11, extra semicolons `;` (aka *[empty-declaration](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.pre#nt:empty-declaration)s*) at the global level are valid. I believe this is occasionally useful for writing macros.

As such, GCC 11 removed `-pedantic` diagnostics for an extra `;` when [`-std=c++11`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#index-std-1) or later is used. See:

- [[GCC Bug 96068]  Extra semicolon outside of a function should be allowed after c++11?](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96068).
- [[GCC Bugs Mailing list] -Wpedantic doesn't warn about extra semicolons anymore](https://gcc.gnu.org/pipermail/gcc-bugs/2021-November/763193.html)
- [[CWG 569] Spurious semicolons at namespace scope should be allowed](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/569.html)

You can restore the old behavior by using a C++ standard older than C++11. Both GCC 11 and clang 6 will emit the old diagnostics if you pass `-std=c++03`.

Alternatively, recent versions of both GCC and Clang support the warning option [`-Wextra-semi`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-Wextra-semi) which specifically warns about redundant semicolons. <sub>Thanks to HolyBlackCat for mentioning this.</sub>

Comment: Thank you. My code uses cpp20, so `-std=c++03` is not viable. I am getting this on a CentOS compiler where I build python wheels. Any other static-analysis available that you know of that can help? 

Could you provide an example where this is useful for macros, as mentioned in this answer?

Comment: @jerin you could have something like an `IF_DEBUG` macro which removes code outside debug builds. Then, `IF_DEBUG(int counter = 0);` to declare a debug-only global variable. You could of course put the semicolon inside the macro argument list, but this may mess up auto-formatting with clang-format, and having the semicolon after a function-style macro is preferred by most developers. On a non-debug build, this macro would expand to nothing and you would have an *empty-declaration*.

Comment: @JanSchultke This can be easily worked around by replacing the macro with something that consumes the `;`, like `do {} while (0)`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you can't do that at namespace scope

Comment: @Caleth At namespace scope you can do `static_assert(true)` to comsume the `;`. And that works at function scope too...

Comment: @jerin the thing I am wondering here is why you care so much, what bad would it do to have an extra ; here and there?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I encountered -Wpedantic being activated in a CentOS system on CI (this one builds manylinux wheels), while I cannot trigger it locally (where I have newer compilers). Fixing this via CI was turning to be cumbersome, so was wondering what was going on under the hood and possibilities. 

Googling did not give me much to go on, hence a question.